# Detect page changes that'd don't refresh in Chrome Extension Javascript + Clay.js

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome

**Background**

I am trying to write a Google Chrome extension to detect whenever a user scrolls down on Facebook, and if they successfully load a new set of posts, change the icon for one of the reaction options for all posts.  I am using [clay.js](http://zzarcon.github.io/clay/) to detect if the div that contains the Facebook feed has resized, which means more posts have loaded / comments have been posted. **This works fine.**

**Problem**

The problem arises when you **swap between pages on Facebook without refreshing.** For example, if you start on your **Home** page, this will work fine.  However, when you swap to your profile, the script no longer runs, **until you refresh the page.**  Once refreshed, the script works perfectly again.  I know I'm missing something about how my file is being loaded, so my question is: **how do I run my script on every Facebook page, without having to refresh between each type of page?**

**Relevant Code** (reaction-changer.js)

```
const fbContentId = "#content"

// on DOM load, watch for future feed scrolling
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', checkFeedUpdate(), false);

function checkFeedUpdate(){
    let currFeed = new Clay(fbContentId)
    // resize occurs whenever the user scrolls down or a comment loads
    // on a prexisting post
    currFeed.on('resize', function() {
        switchAllIcons()
    });
}
```

**Manifest** (some elements omitted for simplicity, notated by ...).  change-icons.js is the script that actually changes icons, which will run fine, if the reaction-changer.js script actually runs.

```
{
    ...
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["https://www.facebook.com/*"],
            "js": ["extension/clay.js", "change-icons.js", "reaction-changer.js"],
            "all_frames": true
        }
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "img/*.png"
    ]
...

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  I've read the Chrome Extension documentation, as well as a bunch of other stack overflow posts, but must have missed a solution somewhere.

Comment: My guess would be something relating to document.addEventListener -- as in, since the page isn't actually refreshing, the DOM isn't loading again.  So, I need to be checking for different pages a different way, I just am not sure about the ideal way to do this with the chrome API!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alrighty, I spent the last 2 hours working on this, and I found a solution that I'm happy with for now (albeit not content with -- but what'll ya do). Basically, the big question that I had in my OP was:

> how do I run my script on every Facebook page, without having to refresh between each type of page?

Well, what I realized is that, yes, refreshing is the solution.  So... what if we force a refresh on Facebook's end, allowing the `DOM` to refresh, and the code to run as expected? I believe that this PROBABLY is actually an underlying issue with how the `Clay.js` library I'm using is implemented.  Anyway, I basically approached the solution by:

1. First, creating a `background.js` file that takes advantage of `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener` -- this function basically let me detect if a tab changed or if the page status was "completed" indicating it has loaded.
2. If it loaded, then I run the function `checkFeedUpdate()` exactly as above.
3. If it changed to a new page (e.g., user clicked from Home to Profile), I force a reload, and then wait for point 2 above to fire.
4. 'background.js`is detecting whether or not these states have happened yet, and relaying the information to`reaction-changer.js`.

Here's the updated bit of reaction-changer.js (in place of document.addEventListener):

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
      // listen for messages sent from background.js
      if (request.message === 'reload') {
        location.reload();
      } else if (request.message === 'start'){
        checkFeedUpdate()
      }
  });
```

Here's the updated manifest:

```
    "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["https://www.facebook.com/*"],
        "js": ["extension/clay.js", "change-icons.js", "reaction-changer.js"],
        "all_frames": true
    }
],
"permissions": [
    "tabs"
],
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "img/*.png"
]
```

And here's what I created for `background.js`:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(
    function(tabId, changeInfo) {
      // read changeInfo data and do something with it
      if (changeInfo.url) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage( tabId, {
          message: 'reload'
        })
      } else if (changeInfo.status === 'complete'){
          chrome.tabs.sendMessage( tabId, {
              message: 'start'
          })
      }
    }
  );
```

If anyone ends up facing a similar issue (it seems like refreshing does the trick, but you can't get it to work without refreshing), it seems that just forcing a refresh might be a good solution.  If there's a better one, please let me know!